# Slow django-channels update - redis

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

[I went trough the tutorial for the new django-channels setup for 2.0](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) and have a problem with speed. It takes several seconds for me to send a message trough  the chat to see that very same message appear back on my client.

I am using the windows redis client and this is the log from sending a single message and waiting:

```
[6060] 02 May 18:39:36 - DB 0: 7 keys (4 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[6060] 02 May 18:39:36 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1990288 bytes in use
[6060] 02 May 18:39:39 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56967
[6060] 02 May 18:39:39 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:40 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56971
[6060] 02 May 18:39:40 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:41 - DB 0: 7 keys (4 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[6060] 02 May 18:39:41 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1990456 bytes in use
[6060] 02 May 18:39:41 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56973
[6060] 02 May 18:39:41 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:42 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56977
[6060] 02 May 18:39:42 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:43 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56981
[6060] 02 May 18:39:43 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:43 - Client closed connection
[6060] 02 May 18:39:44 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:56983
[6060] 02 May 18:39:46 - DB 0: 7 keys (4 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[6060] 02 May 18:39:46 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1990792 bytes in use
```

All my code is copy pasted from the tutorial. Could the issue lie in the redis config? I am simply using the default config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, the link I used for the windows installer was not the "latest stable" as I thought it was. Updating from 2.4.0 (or something) to 3.2.100 yielded instant responses just like I wanted it to be.

This was a non issue if I just used the correct installer from the beginning.

Comment: Don't use windows and your life will be a lot easier. : )